# Why does executing php via javascript work?

Tags: javascript, php, client-server

Can someone explain a step-by-step of the request and response cycle in this scenario? And yes, it does work (if you have a working php backend).

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var test = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";
    console.log(test);
}
```

**Please** don't parrot the wikipedia definition of AJAX or that php is server-side and javascript is client side, I'm aware of these things.

My issue is, I can't wrap my brain around which comes first in this scenario. My thought is that the js gets executed first and a request is sent to the server but wouldn't that basically be AJAX? And if the js isn't executed first, how could the server possibly know to execute the php (i.e. echo "test") instead of just serving a plain text version of the php tag?

Comment: This is more likely to be a case of PHP being used to write the javascript, which it then sends to the browser as an initial request; and the browser then executes that javascript.... nothing to do with Ajax.... but as you haven't shown the whole code, or explained what you're doing, that's only supposition

Comment: This isn't a practical case, I was just curious. I try not to mix my peas and potatoes much in practice, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at it as layers. As I'm sure you are aware that php runs on server and javascript on client. This is how i think it flows

- the page being rendered has to come from somewhere and in this case it is the server, luckily this is also where php gets executed so all php code has run before being sent to the server. i.e: even the echo code
- echo test has already run in the server and the string 'test' has been produced in a rather fortunate place - in a javascript variable declaration.
- so as we can see, the server just sent "var test = 'test'" and does not do any javascript so the 'var' is of no importance to the server
- when this reaches the browser from the server, this actually makes sense and is executed!

thus, to the server, 'var test = ' is just the string 'var test = "test";' while to the Javascript in browser it means that the variable test contains a string 'test'

Edit: if used in a for loop of a page sent from the server, when the page reaches the browser wherever the the echo php script appears, there is already the echoed string

Answer (score 1):

You request a .php file from the server which it then parses and then renders for serving to the client. In the rendering process echo is outputting a string so `var test = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";` becomes `var test ="test"` in the output. The browser interprets the output (html) and executes any of the javascript at that point. There is no Ajax involved in the scenario you have give which is why you may be getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) PHP prepares the page to be parsed by your browser.  The actual source code sent to your browser is:

```
var test = "test";
alert(test);
```

You should be able to view source on the resulting page and see this.  You're not making a server-side call, you're just loading up text into your browser page via PHP

Comment: Ah ok, but if I put it inside a js for loop. e.g.

 for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  var test = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";
  console.log(test);
 }

How does that work?

Comment: As junior put above, exactly the same.  Anything you put via PHP gets resolved before ANY javascript runs, so the actual javascript being evaluated on the page has var test ="test"; again.  Your loop is in javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try put it as simply as possible. You know that PHP is server side and JS is client side and you're correct in that aspect.

PHP as a language runs whatever it does to generate HTML content to be pushed to the client (browser). So when you run your javascript:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var test = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";
    console.log(test);
}
```

The PHP is evaluated before the javascript ever know's it's done anything. Essentially making your little script look like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var test = "test";
    console.log(test);
}
```

There is no ajax involved in your script above.